# Data binding with Bottom sheet in android with kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, data-binding

How to use data binding with bottom sheet dialog in kotlin.I am facing problem to use data-binding with bottom sheet dialog

Comment: What issue are you having? What have you tried?

Comment: I was trying to use data binding with bottom sheet dialog. but later on, I have found how to do it. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have resolved the issue by converting the bottom sheet into data binding like this:

> **bottom_sheet_pick_loc.xml**

```
<layout >
.....
</layout >
```

> **In Activity or Fragment:**

```
val bottomSheet = BottomSheetDialog(this@MainActivity)
    val bindingSheet = DataBindingUtil.inflate<BottomSheetPickLocBinding>(
        layoutInflater,
        R.layout.bottom_sheet_pick_loc,
        null,
        false
    )
    bottomSheet.setContentView(bindingSheet.root)
```